# How to change default custom theme for login & register page in magento?

Tags: forms, magento, authentication

I'm currently creating a magento store. I wish to use some custom jquery login & register form similar to [fab.com](http://www.fab.com). Did any one know how to change the default login & register template in magento & how to include a custom login form. 
Any suggestions from magento experts?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read the [Designer's Guide to Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/)